# Asymptotic confidence interval for $X \sim U(0,a)$ with $a>0$ unknown

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

**Problem:** Let $X \sim U(0,a)$ with $a>0$ unknown. Find an asintotic confidence interval for $a$ at 95% using a transfomration which preserves the variance.

**Attempt:** I tried to use the method of moments to get $\overline a= 2\overline X_n$ and then $$ \sqrt{3n}(2\overline X_n-a) \sim N(0,a^3)  $$ and look for a function $\phi'(a)^2a^3=1$, but I don't know if it makes any sense.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure about the big picture here, but it's clear you've made a minor error with the variance: it has the wrong units.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen why? I think $\mathbb V(2\overline X_n) = 4\mathbb V(\overline X_n)= 4a^3/12n$. Is that wrong?

Comment: @Maffred $\mathbb V(X_1)=a^2/12$.

Comment: With this family of distributions, it's generally better to make all inferences functions of $\max\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}$ than of $(X_1+\cdots+X_n)/n.$ For example, what if you get a confidence interval $(u,v)$ where $v<\max\{ X_1,\ldots,X_n\}\text{ ?}$ In that case you would KNOW, based only on the data, that the confidence interval fails to capture the true value of $a. \qquad$

Comment: @maffred what Nch said. But you don't need to do the calculation to see it's wrong. Variance has units of mean squared so must be proportional to $a^2.$ Also endorse what MH says, though I don't know what's intended "for the purposes of the exercise". If you have a sufficient statistic and are not using it you're generally leaving money on the table.

Comment: Re @MichaelHardy's Comment: Denote the max of the $X_i$ by $W.$ Show$W/\theta \sim \mathsf{Beta}(5,1)$ and use this dist'n to find $L$ and $U$ such that $P(L \le W/\theta \le U)  = .95.$ Then exact 95% CI is of form $(W/U, W/L).$ Maybe not the solution to your 'asymptotic' exercise, but certainly a better CI than using $\bar X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A confidence interval based on the asymptotic normality of the sample mean $\bar X$ of a random sample $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ from $\mathsf{Unif}(0, \theta)$ is relatively easy to find and
has a familiar form, but such an interval depends on approximations, which improve with increasing $n.$

**Mean-based CI:** Even for relatively small $n$ the mean $\bar X$ is roughly
normally distributed. Because $Var(X_i) = \frac{\theta^2}{12},$ we have $Var(\bar X) = \frac{\theta^2}{12n},$ so that the standard error of the estimate $\check\theta = 2\bar X$ is $SE(\check\theta) = \sqrt{\frac{4\theta^2}{12n}} =
\frac{\theta}{\sqrt{3n}}.$

Then a reasonable 95% CI for $\theta$ is of the form
$$2\bar X \pm 1.96\frac{2\bar X}{\sqrt{3n}},$$
where we rely on the approximate normality of $\bar X$ and the
approximation $SE \approx \frac{2\bar X}{\sqrt{3n}}.$

Specifically, for the case $n = 5$, this amounts to $2\bar X \pm 1.012\bar X.$ Because of the two approximations
involved (normal distribution of $\bar X$ and estimated SE) we are entitled
to wonder whether this style of CI actually provides the advertised 95% coverage. As the simulation in R below shows, coverage for $n = 100$ is nearly 95%.
[about 90% for $n=5$; about 94% for $n = 25].$

```
set.seed(130);  m = 10^6;  th = 10;  n = 100
av = replicate(m, mean(runif(n,0,th)))
fact = 2*1.96/sqrt(3*n)
cover = (2*av - fact*av < th) & (2*av + fact*av > th)
mean(cover)
## 0.946996
```

Note: The vector `cover` contains a million `TRUE`'s and `FALSE`s; its `mean` is its proportion of `TRUE`s.

**Maximum-based CI.** The maximum $W$ of the $n$ observations can be used
to obtain an exact 95% CI for $\theta.$ By looking at CDFs, one can show that $W/\theta \sim \mathsf{Beta}(n,1).$ Then choose $L$ and $U$ so that

$$0.95 = P\left(L \le \frac{W}{\theta} < R\right) = 
P\left(\frac 1 U \le \frac{\theta}{W} \le \frac 1 L\right) 
= P\left(\frac W U \le \theta \le \frac W L\right).$$

For the case, $n = 5,$ and $L, U$ the 3rd and 98th quantiles of $\mathsf{Beta}(5,1),$ respectively, we have the interval $(W/.996, W/.496),$ which has exactly 95% coverage probability.

```
qbeta(c(.07,.98), 5, 1)
## 0.5875159 0.9959676
```

Answer (score 2):

The transformation which preserves the variance is $\phi(\overline X_n)=\ln(2\overline X_n)$. You can also use any other logarithm. By Delta-method, you can check that
$$
\sqrt{n}\left(\ln(2\overline X_n)-\ln(a)\right) \xrightarrow{d} N(0,1/3)
$$
as $n\to\infty$. If we want to get the standard normal limiting distribution, then 
$$
\sqrt{3n}\left(\ln(2\overline X_n)-\ln(a)\right) \xrightarrow{d} N(0,1).
$$

Using this fact, the asymptotic confidence interval can be constructed as follows: 
$$
0.95=\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbb P\left(-1.96\le\sqrt{3n}\left(\ln(2\overline X_n)-\ln(a)\right)\le 1.96\right) =\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb P\left(2\overline X_n\cdot e^{-1.96/\sqrt{3n}}\le a\le 2\overline X_n\cdot e^{1.96/\sqrt{3n}}\right).
$$